# What is the blue swirl of wind that drains my magicka in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Occasionally I'll encounter a swirl of blue wind which drains my Magicka. Are these traps that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: when does this happen?  Out doors in the wilderness or in dungeons?

Comment: I've noticed it in dungeons. Labyrinthian for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Labyrinthian (for the Staff of Magnus) the effect is a quest specific drain that occurs when Morokei speaks to you from deeper inside the dungeon. It occurs in very specific areas so it feels trap-like but they're unavoidable and don't appear anywhere else in the game (in my experience).

Comment: Confirmed this here: http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Morokei_(creature)

Comment: 6 year break from skyrim @BrianKelly?

Comment: I was poking around my StackExchange profile and complete forgot I asked this question. But I have actually picked up Skyrim again, this time on the Xbox One :-)